# Unable to use React Router Function

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am building a new web app using react js with react router. When I start the application, getting an error as "`You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>`".  I have shared my Main.js and Index.js file.

[image]

**Main.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Route,NavLink,HashRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./components/About";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import DashBoard from "./components/DashBoard";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <hashRouter>
        <div>
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
          <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
          <ul className="header">
            <li><NavLink  to="/">Home</NavLink ></li>
            <li><NavLink  to="/Dashboard">Dashboard</NavLink ></li>
            <li><NavLink  to="/About">About</NavLink ></li>
            <li><NavLink  to="/contact">Contact</NavLink ></li>
          </ul>
          <div className="content">
            <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/Dashboard" component={DashBoard}/>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        </hashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

**Index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Main from './Main'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Router` need to be outside the `Main`, so your index.js should look like this :

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
        <Main />
    </HashRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: After moving the Router into the index.js file, getting an error as "You must specify the "to" property"

Comment: This is because of the `NavLink` the syntax you provided is `<NavLink  href="/contact">Contact</NavLink>` yet it should be : `<NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>`

Comment: updated the above to changes in question and your solution is working fine for me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix now, just update versions of dependencies in the package.json and re-install.

"dependencies": {
"google-map-react": "^1.1.5",
"mdbreact": "^4.25.0",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "3.3.0"
},